# Should pmr containers with different allocators compare equal?

Tags: c++, comparison-operators, allocator, c++pmr

Say I have a container that uses a hardcoded pmr allocator to store data. What is the consensus among the C++ community: should `operator==()` compare equal on objects that only differ by their allocator or should it be [strongly ordered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering)? I can see arguments for both cases.

Possible implementation of a container:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIJIapAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcQm2mPaOAkIETMQEWT5%2BXJXVGXUNBEUR0bF6CvWNzTltQ929JWUSAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutuyEP4qAfYJhoAghtbO5j7h2wsJACeAPrEmAqLy5jnlxuZk2DG2Xj2BzcDWITFeAOugKGxC8Dl2YloqGQ7yYAHcGph3g5iICTAB2KzXXZU3ZeNJGNG0DGiIjEd4EV5JB4HAAiuxOIBASRYcUFnleL2ISQQeCx6MxTBZkP5ICirwI/3WF3WFKu1LRXiIu2AmAI2MZ8pZEFm%2B3JgL1eq%2BBCWDAZTIVJHeBx1erJ3JJlOpctleK%2BhIIxAgQfdrPZnNdFpIj15ZKspO5szt9qpIED5uZHpTUcVaczVJT/t11N9Fb1TANqF2qE5MMV6z9bYgaAYQ3jwfxYeJZgAbI2CAhYtbywGs47nb3o%2B8kzzR%2BPiAA6IsF7Wlm1%2BhHT%2Bcstkch6b1lekkl7f7q6hAi7FhMUJWy86nfK6GwpUEdAC1Xq0hdi4DRzl2KIvCoKhYgvG89WVIURReBhUCIBgZXecDINiT5vl%2BFYHyiYlyUwqD13QBUmCtQCSNiNc0gAL0wKi%2BR/AUEIFBgvEZd5njeHCfiWFYrV3GDKypeDhTYsUJSldCz2/X8VTVDVsF2JImHLYdSiI9s3wPINsRDAkiTRUTazzQz%2BxMqIU3U6trxuA88CoXZIyXNswMnW0Dz1JJiDvKgIHMMwABVx1eNEvl2McHgUVhMDAMATAAVjcBhgozByfRLG9fQ4eZaE4ZLeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrD5PCuWBHhSAITR8vmABreIAA41y6sxko0IdkrMUlJC4ZKpHWaRCo4SQStairOF4BQQESFqyvy0g4FgGBEBQVAWCSOhYnISg0EO464mALgzACLAADcZUwAA1PBMBxAB5TlSqamhaHVYgVogKIFqiUIGleTgmvOthBA%2BhhaEhjbSCwR8jHEZH8C%2BBw8Hu74FswVRMGQA1VnKu8qgW2g8EIiGPCwBbwzwFgoc2qgDGABRXver7GFZmRBBEMR2CkAX5CUNQFt0NoDCMFAassfQaZWyB5ibGpu04ABaAB1dFdi1j6FANrWTh5YBOIViwzHKuxiY1lwGHcTwWj0YJQj6UoBjaFI0g10ZWjyP2Mimfo4nGKp7c6YYmhdsZ2ij2oY9Dr3w9sGOA8GZOPemb35gEv45n0Ir5uRyqOF2VQuqHLWh0kI1kGQICzDXMxXNwQhEw2LhZl4datFmeZxyYLA4ioma5tIFmxrXdYh1JUkuHWDQNEkSQuskdZSFK8ry%2BW1bmta%2BZtr2xYCCSA1Ts7A6jvoYhwnizgq5ruuG6bm7W94TB8BZPBfzafggtRDiFFoA8WKh1DI2lqQHEMIkiswKiXbeC1y4fQNBfe8qAXLP1rvXYAjdm6t1ch4C6d99iNV7ofDag9SCdQGsXWavAWbJR6kOdYt1q4AE5OHJQmslUkg1kFlyWrYA%2B/c2q0JABNNcXBRqcKmqSfqG8urJSHEOBh6xS67xEeImhM0zBaN4HvKhA95h40BhkeIQA)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <array>

struct alloc_aware_ctr
{
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
    auto get_allocator() {
        return allocator_;
    }

    alloc_aware_ctr(allocator_type allocator = {})
        :   allocator_{allocator}
    {

    }

    auto operator==(const alloc_aware_ctr& other) {
        return allocator_ == other.allocator_;
    }

    allocator_type allocator_;
};

int main()
{

    std::array<std::byte, 10> buffer;

    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mbr{buffer.data(), buffer.size(), std::pmr::null_memory_resource() };
    std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte> pa{&mbr};

    alloc_aware_ctr a;
    alloc_aware_ctr b{pa};

    if (a == b) {
        printf("They are the same!\n");
    }

}
```

This one distinguishes the allocators ^^

Comment: "_I can see arguments for both cases._": I can't think of a reason that they should not compare equal. `==` is for comparing values, why should it matter how these values are stored?

Comment: @user I understand your point. It's more a question of semantics: Is the allocator _conceptually_ part of the type or is it not? If it is part of the type, two types should compare equal when their fields compare equal, as this is what you expect. But I've come to believe that pmr allocators just have no better place to go than into the type, even though they shouldn't conceptually be part of it.

Comment: I expect that `==` on a containers tells me whether the elements of the containers are equal (in an ordered or unordered manner). I do not expect the type of the container to matter. For example if it was possible to compare `std::array<int, 42>` with `std::vector<int>` I would expect them to compare equal iff the vector has length `42` and all corresponding elements are equal. I would not expect the type difference to affect this. So even if the allocator is conceptually part of the type, I don't see why it should compare unequal. Type equality can be checked in other ways at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a reason that the allocator should matter. `==` should compare the values of the elements of the container for equality. How the values are stored shouldn't matter. The allocators comparing equal is only relevant to deciding whether one can be used to deallocate storage allocated by the other. Some allocator types may never compare equal.

This is also what the *Container* requirement in the standard library requires.

However, if the *type* of the allocator was different, then typically the resulting containers are not comparable at all. But I would still say that if they are comparable, they should not compare unequal just because of the allocator.

Answer (score 2):

The standard defines a set of [requirements for containers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/container.requirements.general#tab:container.req), and additional [requirements for allocator-aware containers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/container.requirements.general#tab:container.alloc.req). The container requirements specify the behavior of `operator==` and `operator<=>` for two instances of containers of the same type (ie: same template parameters). This is *not* in the section for allocator-aware containers, and nothing in that section changes its behavior.

The behavior for `operator==` is that it's equivalent to using `std::equal` on their iterators. The [behavior of `operator<=>`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/container.requirements.general#14), if `T` itself provides ordering, is equivalent to `std::lexicographical_­compare_­three_­way`. Neither function cares about the allocator's value.

Therefore, comparisons between PMR-containers (as defined by the standard library's rules) are *required* to work and are required to *ignore* the actual `memory_resource`s that they use.